# Ошибка JVM при попытке дебага в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Добрый день.
При попытке дебага теста в Eclipse (Debug as -> JUnit Test) вылетает ошибка:
         [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Заранее благодарен.

Итак, скачал файл agent.dll и закинул его в папку Windows\System32.

В командной строке написал: java -agentpath "C:\Windows\System32\agent.dll"

Получил системную ошибку java.exe:

> Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует javai.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу.

Копаю дальше.

Comment: Как один из вариантов, что Eclipse не хватает прав обратиться к программе. Попробуйте запустить от имени администратора Eclipse и проверить, не влияет ли антивирус, отключив его временно.

Comment: Отключил все (антивирус, брандмауэр и тд), запустил от имени администратора- не помогло. Ошибка осталась.

Comment: На enSO есть [такой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633502/cannot-connect-to-vm-in-eclipse), но там радикально все ПО для разработки переставляют и отключают антивири с фаерволами.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась удалением и новой установкой Java и Eclipse.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/175227)

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, мимо. Это **ответ,** опубликованный самим автором вопроса.

Comment: @Arhad И что вы хотите этим сказать? такие ответы не требуются и их надо удалить.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, я имел в виду, что это не исключительно благодарность. Её можно убрать, и полезная часть ответа (первый абзац) всё равно останется ответом.